# On 'loaded' event or something for MVC partial view data

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC partial view that I load into a jquery dialog.

I wish to look at one of the fields that holds an email address.  Once the dialog, and subsequent MVC data is loaded, I wish to perform the following logic...

```
if ($('#fldEmail').val() != '') {
    $('#fldEmail').css('color','red');
}
```

The problem is, using the $(document).ready event is too soon to perform this logic since the MVC data hasn't loaded yet.

Is there another event of some kind that fires once the data has loaded fully?

Comment: Show you code where you load your **"MVC data"**

Answer (score 0):

Put your function in your js file that is included in the _Layout.cshtml file. Then it will be triggered at the "correct" document ready event.

Comment: This method did fix another event based problem I had.  It fires after $(document).ready() has fired in the child view, and therefore after any javascript within that event.  Thanks for that!  Big help! However still seems to fire before the MVC data is fully loaded from what I can tell.

Comment: Do you load your PartialView with jQuery load function? If you are doing it like that you have to add a callback function to your load function to catch the event.